# How to make the animation smoother when one of the list is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of elements. On clicking each element they get removed from the list with some animation. The scenario is, when an element is removed from the list the rest of the elements move up without any animation. So can I make this smoother instead of just jumping. Here is my code block

**Style**

```
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li.removed-item {
    animation: removed-item-animation 1s cubic-bezier(0.55, -0.04, 0.91, 0.94) forwards;
    /*transform origin is moved to the bottom left corner*/
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

@keyframes removed-item-animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotateZ(0);
}

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(600px) rotateZ(90deg);
    }
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('removed-item').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
              $(this).remove();
           });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvku3fno/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) first and then .remove() after it is finished.

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('removed-item').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function (e) {
        $(this).slideUp(function(){
           $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

You can also control the slideUp animation duration if necessary

> .slideUp( [duration ] [, complete ] )

```js
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('removed-item').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function (e) {
        $(this).slideUp(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li.removed-item {
    animation: removed-item-animation 1s cubic-bezier(0.55, -0.04, 0.91, 0.94) forwards;
    /*transform origin is moved to the bottom left corner*/
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
@keyframes removed-item-animation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotateZ(0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(600px) rotateZ(90deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In this case you are removing the elements we are just hiding I want to remove the element too.

Answer (score 1):

If you add height to your remove-item-animation of lets say 50px at 0% and 0px at 100% the lists will animation up when one it getting removed.

```
@keyframes removed-item-animation {
    0% {
        padding: 0px 10px;
        height: 50px;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotateZ(0);
    }
    100% {
        padding: 0px 10px;
        height: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(600px) rotateZ(90deg);
    }
}
```